# Meaning of " few heads between them"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What does 'few heads between them' mean? The context is an old story where the sentence continues like this:

"... and they had eaten that down to a **few heads between them**, a sorry prospect in a place where even a handful of prishoc weed was not to be had without sowing it."

The site where the text appears is e.g. this but similar ones can easily be found with a Google search.

http://www.ricorso.net/rx/az-data/authors/g/Griffin_G1/comm.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment you quoted consists of two separate parts:

"Between them" in this case refers to a summarized count of something within a group of people.

> Tom brought two cakes, and Luci brought three. They had five cakes *between them*.

> Last Friday, our bowling club went to a restaurant, and their card reader was broken. The bill was 50$, but we only brought 45$ *between us* in cash. I had to run over to the next ATM.

The other part is "down to a few heads". This basically means that the count or the amount of something was reduced to the new number given.

> On the weekend, we bought a big box of cookies. But since, the children ate the cookies *down to a few crumbs*.

In your example sentence, the group ate cabbage. They *between them* ate most of the cabbage available, so only a few heads of cabbage remain. They *between them* ate the cabbage *down to a few heads*.